# How to add watermark when converting to more than one video with -s option?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, encoding

I have a problem adding watermark to my video. I'm converting a video into 5 different resolutions using the -s option.

what I've tried:

```
waterMark="\"movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]\""

resolutions=$(echo -e "${resolutions} -s ${newX}x${myY} ${map} -vcodec libx264 ${options} 
-vf ${waterMark} ${NEW_FILENAME}_${myY}p.mp4")

ffmpeg -i $FILENAME "${resolutions}"
```

here's the echo of the command:
echo "ffmpeg -i $FILENAME $resolutions"

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4  
 -s 1728x720 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_720p.mp4 
 -s 1152x480 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_480p.mp4 
 -s 864x360 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_360p.mp4 
 -s 576x240 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_240p.mp4 
 -s 344x144 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_144p.mp4
```

I don't know what the error is, all i'm getting is part of the code in red:

> ```
> Metadata:
>   handler_name    : VideoHandler
> Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s
> Metadata:
>   handler_name    : SoundHandler
> ```

this part in red*

> -s 1728x720 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_720p.mp4 -s 1152x480 -map
>   0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental
>   -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_480p.mp4 -s
>   864x360 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict
>   experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png
>   [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]"
>   test_360p.mp4 -s 576x240 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac
>   -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark]
>   overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" test_240p.mp4 -s 344x144 -map
>   0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental
>   -movflags faststart -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in

the strange part is, if I run the code I get from echo `"ffmpeg -i $FILENAME $resolutions"` from the terminal, it does work! but it's not working from bash

I also tried adding the watermark right after -i $FILENAME

```
ffmpeg -i $FILENAME -vf "movie=/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" $resolutions"
```

but in that case only the first video comes out with a watermark.

Comment: Is specifying multiple output resolutions in one command faster than doing it in separate calls? If not you could just use a `for` loop that executes `ffmpeg` five times.

Comment: If the output from `echo works`, but directly calling `ffnpeg` doesn't: Maybe the quotes are the problem. Have you considered writing the output of echo into a variable (`tocall=$(echo "ffmpeg -i $FILENAME $resolutions")`) and then calling this variable (`$($tocall)`)?

Comment: @Tim I get `[NULL @ 0x2452760] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[watermark];'
[watermark];: Invalid argument`

Comment: but your suggestion lead me to solution. eval $tocall worked! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by running the ffmpeg command with eval.
eval takes a string as its argument, and evaluates it as if you'd typed that string on a command line.